# No padlock appearing in address bar

Tags: html, https

I've moved my website (with the exception of the index page) to a secure folder on the root called /mcc. When I open pages, I thought the baddress bar would change to http: and a padlock would appear, does anyone know why this is not doing this.

Thanks
Ross

Answer (score 3):

The padlock item is shown when a page is retrieved over HTTPS (and there aren't any problems with the certificate).

Whatever you have done to secure the folder (you didn't specify), it doesn't appear to have included loading the page using HTTPS.